PLC delta DVP28SV controls maximum how many servo axes
I want to use PLC DELTA DVP28SV11T to control 6 servo motors but I can only control 4 motors. When using the 10khz output pulse at Y10 and Y13 to control the 5th servo motor, it cannot run. How should I solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This seems like a question that Delta should be able and willing to answer.  It is not all that likely to be answered here. (I worked in industrial automation for many decades but didn't use Delta products.)
